# python download folder of text files

Tags: python, python-requests, read-write

The goal is to download GTFS data through python web scraping, starting with https://transitfeeds.com/p/agence-metropolitaine-de-transport/129/latest/download

Currently, I'm using `requests` like so:

```
def download(url):
    fpath = "prov/city/GTFS"
  
    r = requests.get(url)

    if r.ok:
        print("Saving file.")
        open(fpath, "wb").write(r.content)

    else:
        print("Download failed.")
```

The results of `requests.content` of the above url unfortunately renders the following:

[image: Screenshot of requests response.]

You can see the files of interest within the output (e.g. stops.txt) but how might I access them to read/write?

Answer (score 0):

I fear you're trying to read a zip file with a text editor, perhaps you should try using the ["zipfile" module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, that python package does not support reading/writing bytes output returned from r.content

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

```
def download(url):
    fpath = "path/to/output/"


    f = requests.get(url, stream = True, headers = headers)

    if f.ok:
        print("Saving to {}".format(fpath))
        g=open(fpath+'output.zip','wb')
        g.write(f.content)
        g.close()

    else:
        print("Download failed with error code: ", f.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write this file into a zip.

```py
import requests

url = "https://transitfeeds.com/p/agence-metropolitaine-de-transport/129/latest/download"
fname = "gtfs.zip"

r = requests.get(url)
open(fname, "wb").write(r.content)
```

Now `fname` exists and has several text files inside. If you want to programmatically extract this zip and then read the content of a file, for example `stops.txt`, then you need first to `extract` a single file, or simply `extractall`.

```py
import zipfile

# this will extract only a single file, and
# raise a KeyError if the file is missing from the archive
zipfile.ZipFile(fname).extract("stops.txt")

# this will extract all the files found from the archive,
# overwriting files in the process
zipfile.ZipFile(fname).extractall()
```

Now you just need to work with your file(s).

```py
thefile = "stops.txt"

# just plain text
text = open(thefile).read()

# csv file
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open(thefile))
for row in reader:
   ...
```